# Bash: Why does [[ zero -eq 0 ]] evaluate to true?

Tags: bash

On Mac and Ubuntu, running this command evaluates to true. Why?

```
[[ zero -eq 0 ]] && echo true
true
```

Comment: As an aside -- `(( zero == 0 ))` is preferable numeric-comparison syntax -- if you're going to use bashisms, might as well use more readable ones. :)

Comment: `-eq` is numeric comparison. Try `zero=1` then rerun your comparison...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-eq` runs a numeric comparison.

When a string is given as an operand, the value of a like-named variable is looked up.

Thus, this becomes equivalent to `[[ $zero -eq 0 ]]`. An empty string has a numeric value of `0`. Thus, unless a different value has been assigned to the shell variable named `zero`, this is equivalent to `[[ 0 -eq 0 ]]`, which is true.

Comment: What a horrendous feature!